# python matrix muultiplication using numpy or pandas on a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a input dataset (acutally it's a H2o Frame, but it can be converted to a pandas or numpy array), with more than 60 million rows. I need to do subtract, multiply and divide each row with with a list of values, like below

```
 Input dataset
    Col_0,      Col_1,      Col_2,      Col_3
    0.221,      0.331,      0.444,      0.555
    0.111,      0.222,      0.333,      0.444
    0.555,      0.323,      0.665,      0.999
    
To be processed with these values from a dictionary
    to_sub : [0.0002,       0.000004,       0.34334,        0.000005]
    to_mul : [1.333,        1.3433,     2.4334,     3.23232]
    to_div  : [1.8888,  1.6666,     1.7777,     1.89898]

like below
(Col_0-to_sub[0])*to_mul[0]/to_div[0],  (Col_1-to_sub[1])*to_mul[1]/to_div[1],  (Col_2-to_sub[2)*to_mul[2]/to_div[2], (Col_3-to_sub[3])*to_mul[3]/to_div[3]
```

For now, I'm using a nested for loop to process each row with the respective values from each array. Is there any other much efficient way of doing this in python using numpy or pandas or any other python libraries?. Also is it possible to make this process generic, meaning the number of columns in the input dataset and the number of values in to_sub, to_mul, to_div  may vary for different process. But number of columns and number of array values will remain the same for the same process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
ops = np.array([d['to_sub'], d['to_mul'], d['to_div']]
out = (df - ops[0]) * ops[1] / ops[2]
```

```
>>> out
       Col_0        Col_1        Col_2        Col_3
0   0.155827     0.266787     0.137788     0.944676
1   0.078196     0.178931    -0.014154     0.755739
2   0.391544     0.260339     0.440303     1.700424


>>> ops
array([[2.00000e-04, 4.00000e-06, 3.43340e-01, 5.00000e-06],   # sub
       [1.33300e+00, 1.34330e+00, 2.43340e+00, 3.23232e+00],   # mul
       [1.88880e+00, 1.66660e+00, 1.77770e+00, 1.89898e+00]])  # div
```

Comment: Thanks, few doubts. should the input dataset be converted to any form? how the input dataset will loop through each  ops array value?

Comment: No need to convert your input data until it can be converted to a numpy array. For the rest, take a while to read how numpy operates. The most important is the number of columns be the same between df and ops.

Comment: By the way, is it the result you expect?